# How do i get a single value from a object using AngularFire2 ListObservable

Tags: angular, angularfire2

When i make a call to Firebase i get back a snapshot, how do i access a single value inside that SnapShot? This is what i have:

```
topics: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

constructor(af: AngularFire) { 
    this.topics = af.database.list('/topics',{preserveSnapshot: true});
    this.topics.subscribe(snapshots => {
    snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
      console.log(snapshot.key)
      console.log(snapshot.val())
    });
  });
```

That code will print to console something like that:

```
   Object {desc: "Answer questions about music!", imgURL: "seta.png", lang: "eng", published: true, title: "Music"}
```

Lets say i only want to get the title from there, how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Javascript docs from Firebase i come up with a solution basically all i had to call the Snapshot child before the value like this:

```
snapshot.child("title").val()
```